# How to assign values to environment variables with dynamic name while parsing similar named XML elements?

Tags: windows, batch-file, xml-parsing, dynamic-variables

I have an XML file in the following manner:

```
<pools>
    <pool>aaa</pool>
    <pool>bbb</pool>
    <pool>ccc</pool>
    <pool>ddd</pool>
    <pool>eee</pool>
</pools>
```

I want to parse these tags in such a way that they will be **assigned to variables** as

**Pool1 = aaa**
**Pool2 = bbb**
and so on

I have tried the below code:

```
echo off
set /a x=0
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=2 delims=<>" %%a in ('find /i "<pool>" ^< "pool_info.xml"') do (
set /a "x+=1" 
call ECHO pool%%x%%=%%a
)
```

And it just prints them properly. I tried the `set` command for assigning them, but it does not work.

I went through many Stack Overflow problems, but was not able to find any solution that would match my requirement. If anyone could please help me out.

PS: The `<pool>` tags count here is 5, however, the count can change, so I want it to be flexible.

Comment: It would help us if you were to show us the `set` command you say is not working for you. Are you using `Call Set "pool%%x%%=%%a"`? or something different? Also the whitespece at the beginning of those lines are assigned to the first token and the string `pool` to the second token, so I doubt very much that your `call ECHO pool%%x%%=%%a` line is providing the output you suggest it is. You will want the third token, `tokens=3`.

Comment: BTW, as you've already enabled delayed expansion, there's no need, _(and it's slower)_, to use `call` with `%%x%%`. You can just delete `call` and use `Set "pool!x!=%%a"` instead.

Comment: @Compo: Thank you for your response. But I am expecting the output in the same way as Mofi has said in his response.

Comment: @Pankaj, unless I'm going demented, or senile, _(no comments please)_, @Mofi, has used exactly the same techniques as in my comments, both with `Call`, and without when using delayed expansion. The only difference is they included the whitespace, _(which is already the default option)_, with their delimiters, and could therefore continue using the second token, if you remove those and stick only with `<>`, the third token will serve you just as well!

Comment: @Compo: Thank you for your response. I am new to this and I am learning. I will make note of your point too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task can be done with:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem Delete all environment variables of which name starts with Pool.
for /F "delims==" %%I in ('set Pool 2^>nul') do set "%%I="
set "PoolCount=0"
for /F "tokens=2 delims=<>   " %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /C:"<pool>" "pool_info.xml"') do (
    set /A PoolCount+=1
    call set "Pool%%PoolCount%%=%%I"
)
rem Output all environment variables of which name starts with Pool.
set Pool
endlocal
```

**ATTENTION:** The delimiters are the two angle brackets, a horizontal tab character and a normal space character. Please make sure that the batch file contains exactly those four characters after `delims=` in that order.

The horizontal tab and the normal space are needed as delimiters to have a working solution independent on leading spaces/tabs on the lines with the `pool` elements.

The wrong token respectively the missing delimiters tab/space resulted with posted code in question in getting element name `pool` output instead of the values of the XML element `pool`.

There is no need to use delayed environment variable expansion in this case.

However, the usage of `call`  to force a second parsing of the command line

```
call set "Pool%%PoolCount%%=%%I"
```

modified already during parsing of the entire command block to

```
call set "Pool%PoolCount%=%I"
```

before execution of `set` is slower in comparison to using [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) as used in the code below.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Delete all environment variables of which name starts with Pool.
for /F "delims==" %%I in ('set Pool 2^>nul') do set "%%I="
set "PoolCount=0"
for /F "tokens=2 delims=<>   " %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /C:"<pool>" "pool_info.xml"') do (
    set /A PoolCount+=1
    set "Pool!PoolCount!=%%I"
)
rem Output all environment variables of which name starts with Pool.
set Pool
endlocal
```

The reason is explained by [jeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463115/jeb) in the DosTips forum post [CALL me, or better avoid call](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1947&start=15#p10681). The Windows command processor searches with using `call set "Pool%%PoolCount%%=%%I"` in the batch file in current directory and next in all directories of environment variable `PATH` for a file matching the wildcard pattern `set.*`. If there is indeed a file found like `set.txt` in one of the directories, it searches next in that directory for `set.COM`, `set.EXE`, `set.BAT`, `set.CMD`, ... according to list of file extensions of environment variable `PATHEXT`. If there is really an executable or script found by `cmd.exe` with file name `set` in current directory or another other directory of `PATH` with a file extension of `PATHEXT`, it executes the executable/script instead of running internal command **SET**.

For that reason it is definitely better to use delayed expansion solution as it is faster and more safe.

The disadvantage is that a `pool` value with one or more `!` is not correct processed with enabled delayed expansion. So once again `cmd.exe` proves itself that the Windows command processor is designed for executing commands and executables, but not for processing data in text files.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... used for double parsing the command line before execution of `set`.
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `set` command line with using a separate command process started in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line within `'` appended as additional arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
set /a "x+=1" 
call SET pool%%x%%=%%a
)
SET pool
```

The first `set` assigns the value in `%%a` to the variable `pool?`

The second `set` displays all of the currently-set environment variables whose name starts `pool`.

`setx` is a command designed to record a variable assignment for future instances of `cmd`. It's an entirely different matter and should be raised as a separate question, but there's plenty of SO items about `setx` so raising it (again) as a separate issue will likely be closed as a duplicate. Best use the `search` facility for `setx`.

Comment: Thank you for your response and the explanation @Magoo